# Как скачать музыку из роблокса

Tags: lua, roblox

У музыки в роблоксе есть id по которому можно ее получить и проиграть. Можно ли как-то по этому id скачать эту музыку? Я залез в код радио в самом роблоксе.

Первое радио:

```
script.Parent.NewSong.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, songid)
    if songid == 0 then
        script.Parent.Handle.Sound:Stop()
    else
        script.Parent.Handle.Sound.SoundId = "rbxassetid://".. songid
        script.Parent.Handle.Sound:Play()
    end
end)
```

Второе:

```
function playSong(id)
    id = id or ""

    if Sound then
        Sound:Destroy()
    end
    Sound = Instance.new'Sound'
    Sound.Parent = Handle
    Sound.Volume = 0.4
    Sound.Looped = true
    Sound.PlayOnRemove = false
    Sound.SoundId = "http://www.roblox.com/asset/?id="..id
    Sound:Play()
end
```

Я пытался перейти по ссылке подставив код, но ничего не вышло.
Вот один рабочий код на музыку 1837434037